# fncychap and polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, fncychap

I would like to use `Glenn` from `fncychap` with `polyglossia` to looks like the following picture but it doesn't work at all

[image]

here's my MNW

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extbook}
%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{محسن}
\section{محسن}
\subsection{محسن}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try to load `fncychap` last.

Comment: yes it's works but i got باب 1 Instead of الباب الاول

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\DOCH{{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter}{\mtchapter}{}{}
\newcommand{\mtchapter}{%
الباب
\ifcase\value{chapter}\or
 الأول
\or
الثاني
\or
الثالث
\or
الرابع
\or
الخامس
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{التحليل التوافقي}
\section{محسن}
\subsection{محسن}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For my case I prefer the small names for the chapternames.. the command

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}}

changes the name of the chapter

and the command 

 \ChNumVar{\Large}                                                  

puts the literal chapter number in the good dimension

Comment: @Educ would you take a look, and find some small improvements, on the last edition of my answer on my publication you commented. Salam for you and touhami, and happy texifiying

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Salam for you

Comment: please @touhami if I added commande for hyperref I get an error. \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = blue,
citecolor = blue,
urlcolor = blue}

Comment: @PolineSandra I am sorry, i can't ansower for now I have no arabtex no xelatex. Can you please ask new question with a MWE?

Comment: that's ok @touhami thank you for all

Comment: @PolineSandra you need to load  `hyperref` before `polyglossia` and see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)