# Add Chapter text with label in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, report

I am using report as document class. For a table of content, default is like in the first picture.
[image: Currently this]
I want to add Chapter in front of each chapter heading like in the second picture. I can't figure out how to do that.

[image: Want to make like this]

Comment: This answer may be helpful to you: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213223/241621](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213223/241621).

Comment: Could you post a small (yet complete) code of what you've tried?